# Variable not posting to what i believe is dynamic image?

Tags: php

I have a very simple port check that i wish to post online/offline status's to what i believe is a dynamic image. Well it don't give me and error or nothing if it's online but it does not post offline or offline it post Resource id #1 Here's my code:

```
<?php
$ip      = $_GET["ip"];
$port    = $_GET["port"];
$online  = "Online";
$offline = "Offline";

$status = (fsockopen($ip, $port));
if ($status) {
    $online;
} else {
    $offline;
}

// Create a blank image and add some text
$im         = imagecreatetruecolor(215, 86);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

// sets background to Light Blue
$LightBlue = imagecolorallocate($im, 95, 172, 230);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $LightBlue);

//Server Information
imagestring($im, 7, 5, 5, '3Nerds1Site.com', $text_color);
imagestring($im, 2, 40, 30, $ip, $text_color);
imagestring($im, 2, 40, 40, $port, $text_color);
imagestring($im, 2, 40, 70, $status, $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Output the image
imagepng($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Can anyone give me helpful info about this?

Here is also my output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is meaningless:

```
$status = (fsockopen($ip, $port));
if ($status) {
    $online;
} else {
    $offline;
}
```

It is also the cause of the problem, because `$status` will never be something printable (the lines inside the conditionals do not change its value at all). It will either be `false` (in which case you will see nothing where you expect "offline") or a resource (in which case you will see something like "Resource id #1").

Replace all of the above code with

```
$status = fsockopen($ip, $port) ? $online : $offline;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if ($status) {
    $online;
} else {
    $offline;
}
```

to

```
if ($status) {
    $status = $online;
} else {
    $status = $offline;
}
```

Just having `$online` in an if-block doesn't do anything by itself. You have to do something with it; that is, assign it to a variable to output later.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `$status` into the image which is the result of an `fsockopen()` call and not the string you specified at the top. Try this:

```
$status = (fsockopen($ip, $port));
if ($status) {
    $status = $online;
} else {
    $status = $offline;
}
```